# Quadratic imaginary field, $d>1$

Tags: number-theory

We have $d>1$, a square-free integer. Consider the quadratic imaginary field $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-d})$. Suppose that $d\equiv{1} \mod 4$ or that it is divisible by two prime numbers.

Prove in both cases that in the ring of integers of $K$, there exists a prime ideal which is not principal, but its square is principal.

Can you help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For $d=1\mod 4$ and $d>1$, the prime $2$ is ramified, but (because $a^2+db^2>2$ for integers $a,b$) is not a norm, so the prime lying over cannot be principal. But its square is the ideal $2$, which is principal. When $p|d$ but $p<d$ for prime $p$, similarly, $p$ is ramified, but the prime lying over cannot be principal (again by the inequality $a^2+db^2>p$ for integers $a,b$ with $b\not=0$), yet has square $p$.

Comment: So what are the non-principal ideals in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{6}]$?

Comment: I don't understand: but (because a2+db2>2 for integers a,b) is not a norm, so the prime lying over cannot be principal.

Comment: Ok I have already understand, sorry

Comment: and in the case that $d\equiv{1}\,mod\,4$?